# Naming convention for MySQL columns/fields, Consistency or Convenience?

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions, naming

I am trying to name colums(fileds) for the tables.

In my table, all columns(fields) follow upper camel case.

So I intend to name a primary key as `Id`.

What are the disadvantages for using upper camel case in columns(fields)? Or is it just fine to use `Id`?

Comment: In general, you can't even rely on case sensitivity for column and table names in MySQL, so you therefore can't rely on camelcase being preserved.

Comment: MySQL objects names are case unsensitive, as most of the RDBMS (all of them that I know in fact) There's no advantage or disadvantages what's so ever. It just matches your personal preferences and style. Ideally you should follow your company or client's naming conventions, and if they don't exists, just build your own.